# javascript window.document in the console

Tags: javascript, html

In javascript when I access `window` via Chrome console and then go to the `document` property I get an object with many kinds of properties:
[image: Document DOM]

But when I access the document like this `window.document`in the console I get a different object it seems:

[image]

The latter one looks like the DOM API which we can use to manipulate HTML.

### Question:

Why are we getting different objects of `document` when we access the `document` object in the above mentioned different ways?

Comment: which browser? can you see the document prototype in the second example?

Comment: Good question but also note that there are variations depending on browser used also

Comment: The console has a mind of its own, and it shows you stuff the way it thinks you want to see it. There's no "standard" for what it does. It's possible that `window["document"]` does something different than `window.document` for example.

Comment: Each browser interprets and displays differently, look in Firefox and compare it to Chrome

Comment: Using Chrome browser

Comment: Don't expect an absolute answer. Keep in mind that the dom is not a javascript object

Comment: You can't find the DOM at the window.document?

Comment: You can access the dom using javascript but it is it's own beast

Comment: Ow thanks a lot, I thought it was a javascript object

Comment: That's just the way chrome's console decided to render all `Document` objects. You can check this with `console.log(document.implementation.createDocument('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', null))`. But Yes, for the js engine, `window.document` **is a js object.** Not sure what @charlietfl tried to say here. Also, indeed, if you want to be sure it won't use fancy representations, use `console.dir`.