# Really - window.document and document inside window is not the same. Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, browser, window

I wonder why one and the same entity has a different representation inside browser `window` object called in console:

1. If we call just `window` inside browser console we'll have a whole browser info. Where the `document` will be represented as object-liked entity included various props and functions (including DOM).
2. If we call `document` directly by `window.document` command we'll have just only the DOM representation of it.

So, why does it happen? I really cannot figure out.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between window, screen, and document in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895202/what-is-the-difference-between-window-screen-and-document-in-javascript)

Comment: No, it's a fully different question. @devlincarnate

Comment: @devlincarnate this is a different question. Delete your duplication mark in my post! I'm not asking about dimensions of the DOM, instead I'm wonder about differents in document and window.document!

Comment: I don't know the proper answer but I assume it is just a matter of interpretation. Chrome developers just assumed that in console, when you type `document` you want to see the DOM, whereas if you want all info you just type `window.document`.

Comment: @OliverTušla haha, just type the what you wrote above - `window.document` and you will be wonder by what you see in console.... You don't right

Comment: Sorry, meant typing `window` and seeing the property for yourself.

Comment: There's this (exact) duplicate [javascript window.document in the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47383223/javascript-window-document-in-the-console) (which has no accepted or upvoted answer and thus is not available as dupe target). It is closed as dupe of [What's the difference between console.dir and console.log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954152/whats-the-difference-between-console-dir-and-console-log) which uses `window.document` in one of its answers as showcase.

Comment: if your app opens a new window.e.g  childWindow=window.open(//some params);  them you have window.document and childWindow.document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the way chrome's developer tools work. They have a few different formats that they can output information in the console. Dom nodes, which are a type of object, have gotten their own fancy implementation, since they're such a common occurrence in web development. So when you do `window.document`, that's the format it chooses to output it.

For other types of objects they output it in a different format, and that's what it's doing when you do `window`. It's true you can expand this to drill into window.document, but the dev tools keep displaying it in the same format, rather than trying to nest one format inside another.

Comment: _"So when you do window.document, that's the format it chooses to output it."_ - Use `console.dir(window.document)` instead of `console.log()`

Comment: @Andreas I don't think he's doing either of those, he's just typing `document` and `window.document` directly into the console.

Answer (score 0):

straight from my chrome debugger:

```
>window.document === document
true
```

The documentantion relays that window.document is just a reference to document.

However even if they refer to the same document, the **document** might contain special getters and setters which overide those of window.document...

Comment: Getters and setters can't tell what expression was used to access them.

Comment: Yes, but windows getters and setters are run first before  documents getters and setters, and they could potentially overide them. I can run you an example if you would like.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Writing just `document` doesn't access it through the Window object, so it doesn't use the getter/setter.

Comment: Yes, absolutely, it's just something that **could** happen, and which might explain the difference in output. I have absolutely no idea if it does. (probbly not)